# Add function to Interface without implementation in all classes

Tags: c#, interface

My question is, In C# If I want to add an another Function in a Interface but I don't want to Implement that function in all classes that are implementing that interface. How can I achieve that ? For example

A interface contain 5 methods and that interface is implemented in 20 Classes. Now I would like to add another method in same interface but I want to implement that function in only 5 Classes and not In 15 classes ? How could I achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not 2 interfaces?

Answer (score 6):

```
public interface IWidelyUsed { ... }
```

This is the one implemented by those 20 classes

```
public interface IParticularCase : IWidelyUsed { ... }
```

This will have the other function

Comment: This assumes you need "coupling" between the 2 interfaces. I don't mean this is wrong, it might be the solution, but the other interface may also be completely separated.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you are correct. I think this is the solution because the OP needs to add a method to an interface but implement it only on certain classes; this makes me think that he needs a specialized interface

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: split the big interface definition into two more specialized ones.

Some theory behind it:
[Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) as a part of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Answer (score 1):

This contradicts the very essence of what an interface is. If an interface `IBlob` defines `void DoAThing()`, it means that any class that implements it knows how to Do A Thing. That's the *contract*. If you want some of your `Blobs` to be able to Do A Thing and some don't, you're essentially saying that Doing A Thing isn't a feature of `Blobs`.

Now, there are some cases where you *do* want all IBlobs to expose DoAThing, but you don't want anything to happen there. You want a default, null implementation. For these cases, we can add an abstract base class between the concrete classes and the interface:

```
interface IBlob
{
     void DoAThing();
}

abstract class AbstractBlob : IBlob
{
     virtual void DoAThing() { } // nothing happening.
}

class BlobThatDoesThings : AbstractBlob
{
     override void DoAThing() { DoSomething(); }
}

class RegularBlob : AbstractBlob
{
   // Inherits the abstract blob's implementation.
}
```

In other cases, though, where you really only need some blobs to implement a method, use the interface specialization method that BlackBear mentioned [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838868/701054).